# Parse timestamp without knowing the timezone

Tags: c#, unix-timestamp, epoch

I am parsing Timestamps from a JSON into C#. Usually these timestamps look like this: `"2017-05-12T14:45:42.7529468Z"`. However I might receive timestamps from other timezones, e.g. a timestamp from GMT+2 - I assume it would look like this `"2017-05-12T16:45:42.7529468B"`.

I used to parse the timestamps with

```
DateTime myTimestamp = myJSON.SourceTimestamp
```

This method doesn't seem to work for timestamps which do not have `Z` at the end.

- Am I assuming the wrong timestamp format for other timezones like GMT+2?
- Or do I need a special parser again?

I tried using

```
DateTime myTimestampExact = DateTime.ParseExact(myJSON.SourceTimestamp, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.ffffffK", null);
```

however the latter returns me an error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: "2017-05-12T16:45:42.7529468B" doesn't look like a valid ISO 8601 timestamp! "B" is not a valid timezone specifier and removing it from the end would make it valid, unfortunately it still wouldn't indicate a timezone making it impossible to know the UTC equivalent. Where is the JSON coming from? Not the browser by any chance?

Comment: I'd expect a GMT+2 timestamp to look like `2019-04-21T18:27:21.225+02:00`

Comment: Nah I just assumed that a GMT+2 timestamp would have a `B` at the end. How would this timestamp then look correctly if it was GMT+2 ? Timestamp would come from an operating system

Comment: @spodger that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!